# PHP and JavaScript Change Status in MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

So I have a to-do list of items that are dynamically populated by user input.  Each has a checkbox next to it, when checked, the status of the to-do item in MySQL database should be modified.

I thought of doing it this way:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' onclick='changeState($theid);' />";
```

where $theid is the row id in the table.

What would the javascript/jquery changeState() function look like to be able to update the database properly?

Here is the javascript code that seems to not work at all (it is placed in the `<head>` of the HTML file:

```
<script language="javascript">

function changeState()
{
    jQuery('body').delegate('input[type="checkbox"][data-state-id]', 'change', function(event){
    jQuery.post('updatedata.php', {
        'rowid': jQuery(this).attr('data-state-id')
        //'state': jQuery(this).is(':checked')
    });
});

}

</script>
```

any ideas why?

Comment: Any details about the MySQL table containing states to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read more about AJAX calls, preferably with `.post()` function, and then update the data in database on the server side.

Good luck.

Based on the examples from [the documentation of jQuery's .post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), you can implement something like this (in JavaScript with jQuery):

```
var changeStatus = function(id){
    $.post("updateState.php", { 'id': id } );
};
```

and on the server side (eg. in updateState.php):

```
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
// here make some query using $id to update the state
// in a manner you prefer
```

**EDIT:**

But I would prefer something like that:

1) on server side, displaying the checkbox (notice different quotes and `(int)` cast):

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" data-state-id="' . (int)$theid . '" />';
```

2) somewhere in JavaScript (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYZBy/) as a proof):

```
jQuery(main_container).delegate('input[type="checkbox"][data-state-id]', 'change', function(event){
    jQuery.post('update_state.php', {
        'id': jQuery(this).attr('data-state-id'),
        'state': jQuery(this).is(':checked')
    });
});
```

3) somewhere on server side (in `update_state.php`):

```
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
$state = (bool)$_POST['state'];
$query = 'UPDATE `states` SET `state`="' . $state . '" WHERE `id`="' . $id . '";';
// here execute the query, obviously adjusted to your needs
```

Comment: except i guess it would be $_POST['id']...okay this looks interesting, going to try it now..

Comment: @Sev Yes, you are correct - I made a mistake. If you will follow the edited version, please keep in mind there may be some errors (maybe `$state` is reverted, I am not sure), but are some improvements, such as: 1) getting rid of inline JS, 2) delegating events, 3) using HTML5's _custom data_, 4) passing current state with the ID, 5) using `onchange` instead of `onclick`, 6) casting as protection from SQL Injection etc.

Comment: @Sev Regarding `$state` being reverted - I have checked it, it is not reverted (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYZBy/)), so you may wish to pass updated state along with the ID.

Comment: I just tried what you said...didn't work.  I've updated my post above to the javascript code I'm using.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Sev As I have proved with jsfiddle, my JS is working perfectly fine. You should not enclose this code within `changeState()` function. You should also get rid of `onclick` event in the `<input>` field. You should also check, where your request goes (eg. with Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Google Chrome) - it probably goes to the wrong place (the URL in `.post()` was relative). Also this may be something on the server-side, with the query. Just fix the JS part and check, whether correct data goes to correct location.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to think of this as: "JavaScript will update the SQL Record", think of this as "JavaScript will tell a API to update that id."

So basically what you have to do is make an API with PHP; and then make JavaScript do the correct API Call via `$.ajax`, that should do the trick.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/api.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'xml/html/script/json/jsonp',
  data: {param1: 'value1'},
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    //called when complete
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    //called when successful
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //called when there is an error
  }
});
```